# Effective way to deliver digital photos to a client with an iPad

Tags: ipad, file

I do not own or have access to any Apple devices. I have a hard time delivering digital photos to client who don't own a desktop or laptop computer and do everything on an iPad.

What service can I use that will make it easy for an iPad user to receive and share his images when they are too large for their email attachment size limit ?

I tried Google Drive with little success and was planning to move to Dropbox, but I don't want to use the client as a "Beta tester" before a settle on a workflow.

Comment: what is size of images? Google has their own photo hosting, photos.google.com. Comes with gmail

Comment: What was your problem with google drive? Which features did you miss?

Answer (score 2):

**The Fancy Solution:** *(Hard, Not Free, Fancy)*

Setup a website for you own and ask the developer (or find some plugin if you're planing to use wordpress (most likely)) to add an option to your website to give the possibility to the client to watch/download only his/her photos from your cloud solution by that specific username/password combination that you provide to them. By this way you can always have a backup from all of the images that you have given to you clients in one place (in case they needed it again) and if they gave the permission to you to share the images you'll be able to add them to your portfolio section of your website easily without hassling about uploading them again to somewhere.

---

**The Good Solution:** *(Easy, Free, Secure (Password Protection))*

[Mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/) is probably the best solution if you want it to be free, easy, secure and kinda fancy. With the free account you'll have 15GB of space, which you can even create an folder on your computer and setup mediafire's Windows/Mac client (not necessary) to auto-upload the content. you'll be able to protect your files by passwords. The only downside of the Mediafire is that it has some ads on the file download page which will not be a big of a problem but it makes it a little bit infancy solution if you're working with some serious clients.

> Alternative: [MEGA](https://mega.nz/) (Easy, Free, Secure, 50GB Space, Ad-Free, Auto-Sync, But Needs
>   App)

---

**The Easy Solution:** *(Easy, Free, Needs App)*

You could use Facebook (messenger) to send their photos at the full size, and almost everyone has/uses facebook these days, it's free, easy to upload but your client will need facebook messanger and it's infancy and not-so-centralized.

---

**The Efficient Solution:**  *(Easy, Free, Registration Needed)*

You could use Telegram messaging app if you just want to deliver photos to the client in an efficient (but not so fancy) way, on Telegram you can send huge files (Up to 2GB per file), it's free, it has secure chat option with message auto-delete feature and it's also available iOS devices, but if your client doesn't have Telegram already it's gonna make the situation ugly a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue where I was needed to send large amount of data to my client (entirely different scenario but data transfer is data transfer).

I tried zipping it and adding a password protection to it. This worked for small amount (lets says around a 100 Mb or so) of data. For a bit larger data I used a screen sharing application, this can also be made password protected.

If you wanna get it done anyhow, then create an apple ID and upload those images to the cloud via your PC. Share this with the client and he/she can download on his/her apple device.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i had to research the site i keep my photos on in order to provide an informed answer. I use smugmug, i pay for the basic plan, there are 4 plans to choose from.

[smugmug download info page](http://help.smugmug.com/customer/portal/articles/93331?b_id=1644)

I have not used this feature but after reading the page it seams like a good option  with several ways to customize how downloads are handled. you can password protect, the file are placed in zip file, the client can request the zip or you can have emailed to you and you can provide the link to your client. They also allow for the sale of your photos or prints through the eCommerce part of their service if you would like go that route. There is much more info at the link i have provided.

there is another option to create a client sharing area "*The Client Area takes our Private Sharing feature to the next level by consolidating the photos you’ve shared with a client in one easy-to-find location on your SmugMug website. No longer do they need to keep track of any links you email them*"

[client sharing info page](http://help.smugmug.com/customer/portal/articles/1963529?b_id=1644)

I am  paying customer of smugmug and i am not affiliated in any other way or being paid to post this. In fact i do not like the user interface for designing ones web page, i find it NOT USER FRIENDLY compared to the old system they had in place when i joined. when ever i try to redesign my site i get frustrated and quit. i have researched some alternatives and have found the prices of those to more then i willing to pay as someone who does not make a living from my photos.

It seems like a good option for the OP and anyone who just want to provide a place for their clients to review the shoot and or pick the photos they would like have.

There are similar services out there.